# Одинаковое изображение на разных девайсах как аватар вконтакте

Tags: android, android-imageview

Есть изображения, мне нужно чтобы сохранялась масштабируемось, как вконтакте на web и android ширина и верхняя часть изображения не изменяется. Нужно сделать также обрезать, только низ. Как повлияет на работоспособность, если обрезать низ во время выводу? Изображения получаю через API, как лучше резать в API или на телефоне. Интересно как в вконтакте это делается. Если не ошибаюсь, это делается scaleType = matrix?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    tools:actionBarNavMode="list">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                local:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                local:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                local:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                local:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatar_image"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/just_avatar"
                    local:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        local:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="15px"
            android:minHeight="15px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/detailBlock">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">
                <LinearLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Photo"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:id="@+id/details" />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Online"
                        android:id="@+id/online" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/friendButtonContainer"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="20sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone">
            <Button
                android:text="Remove from friends"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/addToFriend"
                android:minHeight="15sp"
                android:minWidth="60sp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:padding="2sp"
                android:layout_weight="6" />
            <Button
                android:text="Send message"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
                android:minHeight="15sp"
                android:minWidth="60sp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
                android:padding="2sp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:layout_margin="5sp">
            <TextView
                android:text="150 Friends"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/friends" />
            <TextView
                android:text="5 Cars"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cars" />
            <TextView
                android:text="... Show more details"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/primary"
                android:id="@+id/moreDetails" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: что это за код, и как он относится к вопросу?

Comment: Я навел полный код layout. Здесь паралакс ефект. Есть только одно изображение, в котором  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` а мне надо чтобы резало только низ, ширина на весь екран - match_parent, и верх изображения чтобы оставался без изменений.